# How to auto size header section using zurb foundation 6?

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

How to auto size header section using zurb-foundation-6?
Something like the video on [zurb.com](http://zurb.com/) which is automatically fitted to screen dimension.

Comment: you  can try `width:100vw` to take full width of view port and for height, you can use `height:100vh`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think we need to go into all the options here but the Foundation 6 documentation includes what they call 'building blocks'.

Here is the top bar:
[Foundation 6 Topbar building block](http://zurb.com/building-blocks/f6-top-bar)

Be sure to check out all the other building blocks as well. They are a great start.